# String Duplication

Tags: c, string, literals

I wonder, is there another solution to modify to string literals and Is the solution really valid and optimal?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strdup(const char *src) {
char *dst = malloc(strlen (src) + 1);   
Space for length plus nul
if (dst == NULL) return NULL;         
No memory
strcpy(dst, src);                      // Copy the characters
return dst;                            // Return the new string
}

int main( void )

{

    const char* s1= " hello ";  // A constant character pointer pointing to the string " serhat".
    char* s2= strdup(s1);
    s2[1]= 'b';
    printf("%s", s2);

    
}
```

Comment: Other than not freeing the memory allocated and the lack of proper comments this looks fine. Best to pick a name for the function that won't clash with any library provided function of the same name. Not sure what sort of answer you are looking for.

Comment: I'd suggest using `memcpy()` instead of `strcpy()` because you already know the length (or would if you captured the return value of `strlen()` in a variable)

Comment: Actually I heard that modern compilers add automatically free that allocated memory.  
So I didn't add but you are right.

Comment: @Paroz The operating system will generally reclaim all memory when the program exits but it isn't anything to do with the compiler and does nothing to keep you from leaking 
 or running out of memory while the program is running,

Comment: There's already a library function in string.h called strdup(). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup. If you don't mean to replace it with your own custom function, you should use a different name.

Comment: @SimonGoater C23 hasn't been ratified yet, [at least not per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C23_(C_standard_revision)) (nevermind by now it should be C24...), so `strdup()` isn't standard C yet.  Nevermind that MSVC *still* doesn't support C99, so who knows what century Microsoft will provide a `strdup()` function (and how long can they refrain from "deprecating" it....)

Answer (score 1):

> is there another solution to modify to string literals...

The code does not *modify* a string literal, it merely modifies an allocated copy. You could use a simpler approach with an initialized array of `char`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char s1[] = " hello ";
    s1[1] = 'b';
    printf("%s\n", s1);
    return 0;
}
```

> Is the solution really valid and optimal?

The code posted is not valid: it does not compile and it is not optimal as you compute the string length twice: once in `strlen` and another time in `strcpy`.

Also note that `strdup` is a reserved name for a POSIX standard function that is semantically equivalent to your function and this `strdup()` function will finally be included in the C Standard in its upcoming version known as *C23*.

Finally `s2` should be freed after use for good style.

Here is a corrected version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *my_strdup(const char *src) {
    size_t size = strlen(src) + 1;
    char *dst = malloc(size);
    if (dst == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else
        return memcpy(dst, src, size);
}

int main(void) {
    const char *s1= " hello ";
    char *s2 = my_strdup(s1);
    if (s2) {
        s2[1] = 'b';
        printf("%s\n", s2);
        free(s2);
    ]
    return 0;
}
```